# Insert number of rows based on value in adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have adapted a VB macro to insert extra rows below values (see "interval" in column A) when there are duplicate instances of associated values occur (see "count" in Column C). More specifically, when there is a count of duplicates that is greater than 1 (0 = no instances, 1 = single instance) with a particular time interval, I want to insert extra rows so that there will be room to insert the duplicated values in order of their appearance.

Images of the Excel data [before execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktJbD.png), [after execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSxCV.png).

Below is the code I have been working with, and it appears to be working. But, it draws an error code every time I run the macro. Could someone please explain why this section of code is triggering the error, and how to fix it? here is the error code that appears: "Run-time error code '13' Type: mismatch", and debugging points to this line of code: `temp = Range("B" & n)`

```
Sub dupeIntervals()
' insert new rows to match how many utterances are in a particular time interval
    Worksheets("Align").Activate
    Dim r, count As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim temp As Integer
    Set r = Range("A:C")
    Set count = Range("B:B")
    LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        temp = Range("B" & n) ' << run-time error 13 / "type mismatch"
        If (temp > 1) Then
            Rows(n + 1 & ":" & n + temp - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Thanks!

P.S. here is the anecdotal explanation of how I am using this macro:
I am transforming utterances from transcribed interviews from continuous data (millisecond time-stamp of when utterance began) into 5-second time intervals. on occasion, there will be more than one utterance per 5s interval, which requires extra rows for inserting those extra utterances within a given interval.

Comment: What is the value of the relevant cell in column B when it errors? Not an integer perhaps?

Comment: all values in column B are the result from a countif function, so i believe they're all integers

Comment: I didn't ask what you believed, but what it actually is when you run the code.

Comment: Looks like `Range("B" & n)` contains an error value. Hit the error, and when VBA breaks on that instruction hit Ctrl+G and type `?n, Range("B" & n).Value` - I expect that to output something like `17      Error2042` - now go to the active sheet and look at what `B17` contains. If that's an error value, then there's your problem: you can't coerce an error into an `Integer`.

Comment: i am not sure which cell causes the error, as the macro has repeatedly performed what I want it to do. but, it still triggers the error code, which i would like to learn why it does so, and if it could cause a problem in the future..?

Comment: If you do exactly what I just said in that comment, the immediate pane will tell you exactly what the problem cell is.

Comment: If there's no error cell, look for empty ones. Or see answer below - that `Debug.Print` statement will print all the problematic rows to the immediate pane (Ctrl+G). Protip: learn to use the debugger and inspect your variables' values at run-time in break mode.

Comment: thanks, @MathieuGuindon.. immediate pane returns "1      count" and the active sheet has the same value (1) as it did before

Comment: well then, bingo. Row 1 contains "count" - what's the numeric value for that?

Comment: So your first cell contains "count" which is not an integer!

Comment: ahh.. the header row! how do i bypass that first (header) row, while allowing macro to remain dynamic with number of rows in column (e.g., B:B)?

Comment: You do realize that your loop quite explicitly goes `LastRow To 1 Step -1`?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop includes row 1:

```
LastRow To 1 Step -1
```

Make that `To 2 Step -1` to skip the heading.

---

That said...

You have declared `temp` as an `Integer`.

```
Dim temp As Integer
```

That means whatever you assign to `temp` must be compatible with a 16-bit signed integer value, i.e. any numeric value between -32677 and 32767.

Some values will implicitly convert to an `Integer`. e.g. 44.634 will assign `temp` with 45.

Some values won't convert though.

- An empty string `""` (or any non-numeric string for that matter) can't be converted to an `Integer`.
- An error value (e.g. `#NA`) can't be converted to *anything*.

Your code is making assumptions:

```
temp = Range("B" & n) ' << run-time error 13 / "type mismatch"
```

It's assuming that the `ActiveSheet` is the sheet you want to be working with. It's assuming `n` has a value that represents a valid worksheet row number - you haven't declared `n`, so it's likely a `Variant/Long`, or `Variant/Integer`, so `n` is probably fine (still, it should be declared).

It's assuming that the value of the range can be coerced into an `Integer`.

Remove these assumptions.

```
Dim cellValue As Variant
cellValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & n).Value

If IsNumeric(cellValue) Then
    temp = CInt(cellValue)
Else
    'skip. cell is invalid.
    Debug.Print "Row# " & n & " contains an invalid value."
End If
```

I'd recommend using a 32-bit integer type (i.e. `Long`) instead of `Integer`.

Comment: changing `LastRow To 1 Step -1` to `LastRow To 2 Step -1` did the trick! + thanks for the valuable (and kind) lessons on declarations and assumptions